# Calling a subroutine from a register and returning (MIPS)

Tags: assembly, mips

Is there a way in MIPS to jump to an address in a register and have $ra updated appropriately, without using jalr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    la $ra, here  // save return address in $ra
    j function
here:
    ...
    ...
function: 
    ...           // function body
    jr $ra        // return
```